# cost of argument passing in scheme

Tags: scheme, argument-passing

I found a interesting thing. Passing argument may deserve consideration, especially in which situation time is important. the code like below.

```
(define (collatz-num n)
  (define (collatz-iter n m)
    (cond
     ((= n 1)
      m)
     ((even? n)
      (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ m 1)))
     (else
      (collatz-iter (+ (* 3 n) 1) (+ m 1)))))
  (collatz-iter n 1))


(define (collatz-iter n m)
  (cond
   ((= n 1)
    m)
   ((even? n)
    (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ m 1)))
   (else
    (collatz-iter (+ (* 3 n) 1) (+ m 1)))))

(define (euler14 n limit)
  (define (help-iter m len n limit)
    (let ((collatz (collatz-iter n 1)))
      (cond
       ((> n limit)
        (list m len))
       ((> collatz len)
        (help-iter n collatz (+ n 2) limit))
       (else
        (help-iter m len (+ n 2) limit)))))
  (help-iter 0 0 n limit))
```

for **collatz-iter**

```
> (time (euler14 1 1000000))
cpu time: 1596 real time: 1596 gc time: 0
```

for **collatz-num**

```
> (time (euler14 1 1000000))
cpu time: 1787 real time: 1789 gc time: 0
```

My question:

1. How big is the cost of passing argument in scheme
2. In function euler14, I let **limit** as argument of help-iter, will it save some time this way? as I have seen somewhere, the free variable will have cost.

Maybe I am too mean.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Did anybody answer your prior question on performance to your satisfaction?

Comment: Same comment as before: this kind of micro-optimizations are not worth your time, better think about reducing algorithmic complexity, or caching the results. And use a profiler, to identify where the problem really is.

Comment: @Óscar López , good suggestion. I thought last night, that there are more things I can do to reduce consuming time than entangled with this problem.

Comment: @GoZoner yes, the answer is that I don't need to concern this problem, it's implementation specific.

Comment: Then give somebody a 'check mark'.

Comment: @kuan291 one word "memoize"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again. this is very implementation specific!

I tested your code and since it does consume memory and do a lot of computations the order in which I tested the two interfered with the second result. I separated the two tests in each file and run each 40 times separately and looked at average running time for both. The differences were num: 1059.75 and iter: 1018.85. 4% difference on average, but might as well be 12% when picking two samples. I'd guess the running time of the same program might differ in more than 4% on average so the difference between these are irrelevant in one run.

You have an extra application in your code so to check how much impact an argument has I made this little test. The usage of the arguments in the base case is so that Scheme won't optimize them away:

```
(define (three-params x y z)
  (if (zero? x)
      (cons y z)
      (three-params (- x 1) x x)))

(define (two-params x y)
  (if (zero? x)
      (cons x y)
      (two-params (- x 1) x)))

(define (one-param x)
    (if (zero? x)
      (cons x x)
      (one-param (- x 1))))

(define numtimes 100000000)
(time (one-param  numtimes))
(time (two-params numtimes #f))
(time (three-params numtimes #f #f))
```

Comment out 2 of the three last lines and make 3 files. Compile them if you can. 
The do the average of several runs. I choose 50 and in Ikarus I get the following averages:

```
      agvms  diffms
one   402.4
two   417.82 15.42
three 433.14 15.32
two2  551.38 133.56 (with an extra addition compared to two)
```

Just looking at the 50 results I see that the times overlap between one, two, and three, but statistically it looks like the average argument cost 0,15ns. `if`, `zero?`, `-` and `cons` and `gc` cost a lot more even if they are primitives. Neither extra applications nor extra arguments should be your concern. Sometimes a different implementation optimizes your code differently so changing from racket to ikarus, gambit or chicken might improve you code in production.

Comment: Very professionally. I think in "three" and "two2" row, comma is period. In practice, it doesn't matter. I am just curious. I should learn more about Scheme compiler.

Comment: Is ikarus still in development? I found its last date is 2008

Comment: @kuan291 Fixed. The creator, Abdulaziz Ghuloum, haven't done anything since 2010 so you're right about development halting, but 0.0.4 is probably better than 0.0.3 even if it's not officially releases (it's what Ubuntu ships). It remains to see if Ikarus will support the current standard, R7RS, but that's the same question I have for the other implementations.

Comment: Ikarus Scheme is exceptional.